# List size of all hidden subdirectories with bash - weird globbing behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, globbing

I wanted to display some information about hidden subdiretories and a noticed a globbing behavior which I don't understand.

`ls .*` gets expanded to the pwd, the parent directory path and all hidden subdirectory paths and then lists the contents of all these directories. That's fine.

`du -s .*` on the other hand only seems to get expanded to the pwd and the parent directory path because it lists only the size of these. I don't understand why its behavior differs from the behavior of `ls`.

Using `du -s .[^.]*` solves the practical problem because it lists the size of all hidden directories. I understand that this works but why doesn't `du -s .*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rephrase my answer, because I have misread the question somehow.

The argument `-s` summarizes the size of directories, and it happens to include the size of all directories below it. They don't get shown at the output.

As the globbing `.*` matches the current directory (`.`), all child directory gets suppressed by `du`.

But it's not THAT simple. This only happens if the parent folder precedes its child folder in the `du`'s argument; then the child folder is not shown.

Probably, at your home folder exist the Desktop, Documents and Downloads folders. At your home folder, try running `du -s D*`. This must show the sizes of these three folders. Now, try `du -s . D*` and `du -s D* .`.

Because the globbing `.*` shows `.` before the `.hidden` folders, they don't get the chance to appear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense! So `du -s .??*`, for example, also works to list all subdirs if their names contain at least two characters after the dot. (Unfortunately, I don't have unough reputation here to upvote your answer)